# how to open a connection after retrieving the connection string from an app.config file in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net

I am new to using the app.config file. I have my connection strings stored in my app.config file and I can retrieve the connection string but I don't know how to open the connection. I am using the app.config to secure the connection string instead of storing it in a static class. I use this method so I can change the string from live to test from one location. Here is my config file. (I am using postgresql)

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="LiveDB" providerName="Npsgql" connectionString="Server=ccmw;Port=5432;Database=Production_Tracking_Database;UserId=postgres;Password=;"/>
   <add name="TestDB" providerName="Npsgql" connectionString="Server=ccmw;Port=5432;Database=PTS_Temp;UserId=postgres;Password=;"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This is how I am getting the string.

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
```

After that I am not sure how to open the connection, I tried connectionString. but open is not in the list of methods.

Comment: you have to use a library to interface with it. read up on `Npsgql`.

Comment: `connectionString` is just a variable of type `string`. You need to use a library and it's associated connection directions. If you look up `Npsgql` which is the provider your indicated for your connection then you can probably find their directions.

Comment: do a simple google search there are plenty of examples on the web as well as on `Stackoverflow` let your fingers do the walking please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a "database connection" in your code will be represented by a connection object of some kind.  In most cases involving MS SQL Server, that's a `SqlConnection`.  For Postgres, however, it's [a `NpgsqlConnection`](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html).  You can create one by calling [its constructor](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionConstructor.html):

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection();
```

Conveniently, one of the constructor overloads accepts a string argument for the connection string:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
```

And it's good practice with objects that control external resources (like a database connection), or with anything that implements `IDisposable` really, to wrap it in a `using` block.  (This is essentially a `try/finally` construct which will dispose of the resource appropriately.)  And since this object [does implement `IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'd use it like this:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
using(var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // use the connection in some way.
    // presumably executing queries against it.
}
```

Comment: Cool this looks good, can I use this in a class so I can just call the method to get the string anywhere in my code. I have two strings one for test and one for live, I would like to change the string in one location if possible.

Comment: @Evanark: In general you wouldn't change the *code* between test and production environments, you'd change the *config*.  So there would be one config entry for a connection string and the code would use that one entry.  In your test environment, the config file has the test DB connection string.  In your production environment, it has the production connection string.  Changing the *code* between environments can very easily lead to problems, not the least of which being that the code in production isn't what was tested.

Comment: Good point, I am learning some good practices here. Thank you for your code example, it works perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following code:

```
static DbConnection CreateDbConnection(
    string providerName, string connectionString)
{
    // Assume failure.
    DbConnection connection = null;

    // Create the DbProviderFactory and DbConnection. 
    if (connectionString != null)
    {
        try
        {
            DbProviderFactory factory =
                DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

            connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Set the connection to null if it was created. 
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection = null;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    // Return the connection. 
    return connection;
}
```

this is the general method in order to create a conenction by a provider/connection string, as in your case.

Comment: @PaulZahra why? it show the correct way on instantiating the connectiong passib trough factory.

Comment: @PaulZahra I think that your comment has some counter productive aspects about it.. I am sure you did not come out of the box knowing how to program.. the answer looks suitable.. this would be the part on the `OP` to now look a the working code and understand it .. regardless in your opinion if you feel that they may not understand.. `One must start somewhere`

Comment: @MethodMan But as the old adage purports, you've gotta learn how to walk before you can run.

Comment: @PaulZahra the point is: use factories, having a difefrent database than usual should be a point in showing how to program the right way. What about the OP will change to SQLServer in the future?

Comment: I learned to `RUN` as you put it in 2 days.. that was `20` yrs ago.. so I never know someone's ability to understand more complex / advance coding techniques, vs simple normal techniques. I do agree however that the `OP` could have used `Google` but sometimes people do not think outside of their own box.. nothing wrong with this answer in my opinion..I've been a senior software engineer for 20+ yrs not and I learned by trying examples and trying to understand the `who what when where how and why` I think this `OP` provided they are not lethargic can do  accomplish the same thing

Comment: @MethodMan Don't judge people by your own standards, they will always dissapoint.